# how to convert Sql server Datetime in different format

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column that store date and time values in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MSS. I have another table that store date and time value as ***string*** in the format 'M/D/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM'.

Now how do I convert  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MSS this format to M/D/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM. After conversion can I able to compare conversion date to the datetime string.
for e.g

A.Date_time = '2013-01-08 12:04:00.000'
B.Date_time = convert ( A.Date_time) -- convert in format M/D/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM
...

if(B.Date_time = 'convert (A.Date_time)' -- how can I can compare conversion date with the datetime string.
...

Comment: NB the first format is the default on your systemn for printing a datetime, it's not stored in that format, it's displayed in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert to string to compare, convert to dates to compare.

```
SELECT <cols>
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN B
  ON A.Date_time = CONVERT(DATETIME, B.Date_time, 101);
```

You may need to clean up data first - when you use a string to store a date (which you should never do for a variety of reasons), anyone can stuff any junk in there without validation. So there is no guarantee that all of your values *can* be successfully converted to a datetime.

**For the changed requirements** we can try sussing the datetime portion of the terrible string in this way:

```
SELECT <cols>
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN B
  ON A.Date_time = CONVERT(DATETIME, 
   SUBSTRING(B.Date_time, CHARINDEX(' - ', B.Date_time) + 3, 255), 101);
```

You can even pull that out first, e.g.

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT B.Date_time, RealDateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, 
   SUBSTRING(B.Date_time, CHARINDEX(' - ', B.Date_time) + 3, 255), 101)
   FROM B
)
SELECT x.Date_time, x.RealDateTime FROM x
-- add joins, comparisons, etc.
```

IMHO you should focus on fixing the data types, not working around the differences. Or at least arguing with the people who designed this mess to clean it up.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. What I am really trying to do is datetime string is came from the vb.net app. it store datetime with other string for e.g. 'work start - 1/2/2013 08:00 AM' So I need to compare only the datetime.

Comment: Those are two different pieces of data. If the date on its own is meaningful, you should parse that out and store it in a different column. As a datetime.

Comment: If you are really lucky, that format is hardcoded in the .net app, if its based on locale, one user trip in to regional settings to twiddle with long date time format, and you are in for some fun. Find who ever did this, give them a slap from me as well.

Comment: Is is possible to do without making different columns. I don't have rights to changes the database. Please help.

Comment: It's not hard coded. The app needs to show timestamp as well as needs to store in database. Ok I will try to clearify what is happening -

Comment: It's not hard coded. The app needs to show timestamp as well as needs to store in database. Ok I will try to clearify what is happening -      lets say I am in the runway track field and I am trying to find out time to finish one circle on each lap. On each lap I set timer. after finishing couple of laps. I click on time to find out how long does it take me to finish each lap. The lap time show like this in app as "1st lap - 1/2/2013 - 8:00 AM' and so on and this value is stored as in db. I hope it will make sense to you all.